# URL specification that allows internationalized domain names?

Tags: url, idn

I'm trying to find the current spec for URLs.  I found [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), but that [doesn't allow non-ASCII characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), like you might find in internationalized domain names (IDNA).

URLs are one of the key bits of the Internet; surely there must be a spec for them?  If so, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internationalized Resource Identifiers (IRIs)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987

> This document defines a new protocol element, the Internationalized
> Resource Identifier (IRI), as a complement to the Uniform Resource
> Identifier (URI).  An IRI is a sequence of characters from the
> Universal Character Set (Unicode/ISO 10646).  A mapping from IRIs to
> URIs is defined, which means that IRIs can be used instead of URIs,
> where appropriate, to identify resources.

---

Note that [Anne van Kesteren](http://annevankesteren.nl/) edits a ["new" URL specification (at WHATWG)](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/) as a "Living Standard", which states to have the goal to "Align RFC 3986 and RFC 3987 with contemporary implementations and obsolete them in the process.".